# Continuous probability for bivariate distributions: How do I know which support to integrate over? And does it matter which dx or dy is first?

Tags: probability, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am struggling to figure out the reasoning for the solution to this problem.

$P(0 \le Y \le X \le 1) = \iint 30/7 x^2 y\,dy\, dx$
Integrating dy over 0 to x and dx over 0 to 1.

I don't understand why we choose to integrate dy first and then dx.  Does it matter?  Is it because Y is closer to 0 than X is?
I "think" I get why dy is integrated over 0 to x, because in the probability Y is between 0 and X.  But I don't understand why then we integrate from 0 to 1.  X is surrounded by Y and 1, not 0.

This one is a little more nebulous to me:
$P(X \le Y) = \iint 3/16 x y^2\,dx\, dy$
Support is $0 \le x \le 2$ and  $0 \le y \le 2$ . Integration for this was set to dx is integrated over 0 to y and dy is over 0 to 2.  Again, I'm not sure why dx is integrated before dy.  Also not sure why I would choose integrating 0 to y for dx.  I know why its y and not x for dx, but why the variable on the inside integral and then the full space on the next integral?

Thank you!

Comment: Draw a triangle with its boundary as lines $y = 0, y = x, x = 1$. Now it is this triangular region that you are integrating over. So if you integrate over $dx$ first, it will be $y \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: Thank you! But why am I choosing to integrate over dx first?  Why not dy?